# Using custom html helpers in an ASP.NET MVC 3 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So, for some hours now, I have been trying to do something that I thought - and still think - should be trivial. Basically, I created a Html helper that I needed to use to apply some CSS attribute to the selected menu of an ASP.NET MVC 3 Application. Here is my Html helper:

```
namespace MVCUI.Extensibility
{
    public static class HtmlHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(
            this HtmlHelper helper, 
            string text, 
            string action, 
            string controller, 
            string selectedCssClass, 
            object routeValues, 
            object htmlAttributes)
        {
            var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selectedCssClass))
            {
                var contextController = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as String ?? "Home";
                var contextAction = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as String ?? "Index";

                if (String.Compare(
                    String.Format("{0}/{1}", controller, action), 
                    String.Format("{0}/{1}", contextController, contextAction), true) == 0)
                {
                    var cssValue = String.Empty;
                    if (attributes.ContainsKey("class"))
                        cssValue = attributes["class"] as String ?? String.Empty;
                    cssValue = cssValue.Trim();
                    if (cssValue.Length > 0)
                        cssValue = cssValue += (" " + selectedCssClass);
                    else
                        cssValue = selectedCssClass;
                    attributes["class"] = cssValue;
                }
            }

            return helper.ActionLink(text, action, controller, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), attributes);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I am using it from a **_Layout.cshtml** file:

```
@Html.MenuLink("Posts", "Posts", "Post", "selected", new { }, new { })
```

For some really odd reason, I keep getting the error:

**Description:** *An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.*

**Compiler Error Message:** *CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'MenuLink' and no extension method 'MenuLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Here is what I have tried:

1. Added `<add namespace="MVCUI.Extensibility" />` to `<system.web.webPages.razor>/<pages>/<namespaces>` section of the **Web.config** file at the root of the **Views** folder.
2. Added `@using MVCUI.Extensibility;` at the top of the **_Layout.cshtml** file.
3. Tried all combinations of (1) and (2) above.
4. Tried the syntax: `@{ Html.MenuLink("Posts", "Posts", "Post", "selected", new { }, new { }); }`
5. Googled, alot! All materials and resources, including our very own stackoverflow, seem to suggest that am doing the right thing.
6. Even tried setting *[assembly: ComVisible(true)]* in **AssemblyInfo.cs**. Well, just in case! ;)

**Disclaimer:** This is the first time I am trying out a html helper in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application.
Where could I be going wrong? Thanks people.

Comment: What do you see in IntelliSense if you type `HtmlHelpers.` in a view?

Comment: Can you call it with `@HtmlHelpers.MenuLink(Html, "Posts", "Posts", "Post", "selected", new { }, new { })`? Or can you call it fully qualified with it's namespace?

Comment: I can see, `Equals`, `MenuLink` and `ReferenceEquals` methods

Comment: @Charlino: I tried what you suggested. Including qualifying `HtmlHelpers` class with the namespace. Its even wierder since it complains that HtmlHelpers is not in MVCUI.Extensibility namespace

Comment: @JohnGathogo weird... where is the file located? It's definitely getting compiled? What happens if you create another separate helper method that's simple simple simple. Try creating it in another namespace and another directory... basically try and find out what could be wrong with your current setup.

Comment: At the risk of insulting you with a silly question, did you rebuild the entire solution after you added the helper? Typically when I get that error it means I forgot to build, even though the extension may be available in intellisense.

Comment: @Charlino The file is in a folder named `Extensibility` that sits at the same level as `Views` folder. I did try having it at the application root but still got the same error... and believe me I will try everything until am able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like someone pointed out in the comments, there was something different about my setup. In my solution, I had changed the **Output path** for my projects - including the MVC project - from the default `bin\` to something like `..\Library\Build\`. No crime there since that setup has worked fine so far.

But, that is what got me into trouble. After I restored the default output path and rebuilt my project the Html helper worked. It continued to work even after I restored back my preferred output path - obviously because the dll in the `bin` folder got updated.

This would mean that the statement `@using MVCUI.Extensibility;` in my **.cshtml** file and `<add namespace="MVCUI.Extensibility" />` in the **Web.config** were *referencing an old outdated dll in the bin folder that didn't have the HtmlHelper defined*. This bothers still. How would I have them reference the dll in my desired output path?

Anyway, I just thought I should post about the experience and the lessons just in case other people find themselves in similar trouble. Thanks people.

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if the file with the extension method says `using System.Web.WebPages` (which has its own separate `HtmlHelper` class) rather than `using System.Web.Mvc`.

Comment: Couldn't this also be happening when the namespace is in the wrong `web.config` because it should be in the views' one?

Comment: Thanks SLaks. The only usings I have on the file are: `using System;`,`using System.Collections.Generic;`,`using System.Web.Mvc;`,`using System.Web.Mvc.Html;`, `using System.Web.Routing;`

Comment: @Silvermind: SLaks comments set me thinking along the same direction. Am trying it out. Now

Comment: Well, not the case. I don't have `System.Web.WebPages` in the namespaces section

Comment: @JohnGathogo You're talking about the `System.Web.WebPages` namespace, but you should have `<add namespace="MVCUI.Extensibility"/>` in the `Web.Config` under the Views. In the `<system.web.webPages.razor><pages><namespaces>` Is it there? BTW Intellisense won't recognize it before you have reloaded your project.

Comment: @Silvermind: That I already did. I indicated in my question. I added the `MVCUI.Extensibility` namespace to Web.config in the Views folder. I get all intellisense. The project even builds. When I try to browse the application, thats where I get the error

Comment: @JohnGathogo, not wanting to keep on guessing but I had issues with extending AjaxHelper, maybe this is a similar issue. I resolved that one by renaming my own namespace, in your case `MVCUI.Extensibility` to the original namespace of the `HtmlHelper`, `System.Web.Mvc` I wouldn't normally steal namespaces but I found no other option.